# Integrating the dirac delta function with a periodic argument

Tags: integration, dirac-delta, periodic-functions

For example $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\delta \big (\cos(x^2) \big)}{x^2} dx$$

I'm just not sure how to handle there being multiple solutions for $\delta (cos(x^2))=0$

Comment: Why would you not write it as a summation of deltas, one at each zero of $\cos(x^2)$?

Comment: That was what I was thinking, but I wasn't sure how to express it.

Would I write $\frac{\Sigma _0 ^\infty \sqrt {\frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2}}}{n^2}$ ?

Comment: DO you know if this converges? I am pretty sure it does not.

Comment: Rellek This is not the correct final answer. Anyway, that sum does converge (although the sum would have to start with 1). The way to see whether or not sums like that (including the sum that appears in the answer that is imho correct) converge is by examining the integral instead of the sum. This is possible because of the monotonicity: You know that the integral must be somewhere between the value of the sum and the value of the sum without its first term. And roughly speaking, $\int 1/x^\alpha\,dx$ converges at 0 iff $\alpha < 1$ and at $\infty$ iff $\alpha > 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Because there have been wrong statements posted, I add a general instruction. For a differentiable function $g(x)$ with zeros $x_n$ of order 1, one defines $$\delta (g(x)) = \sum_{n} \frac{1}{\vert g'(x_n) \vert} \delta (x - x_n)$$
Check out e.g. Wikipedia. The reason why one chooses this definition is because it is practical. Check out the two approaches below that give the same result to get an idea why this definition is 'right'.

---

First of all, I cast $\delta (\cos x^2 )$ into standard form: The zeros of $\cos x^2$ are $x^2 = \pi (n+\frac 1 2 ), n=0, 1, \dots$. I.e. for every $n$, there is precisely one positive zero. The derivatives are:
$$\frac{d}{dx} \cos x^2 = 2 x \sin x^2$$
For $x = \sqrt{\pi (n+\frac 1 2)}$, this gives
$$2 \sqrt{\pi (n+\frac 1 2)} \cdot (-1)^{n+1}$$
Thus,
$$\int_0^\infty dx\,\frac{\delta (\cos x^2)}{x^2} = \int_0^\infty dx\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi (n+\frac 1 2 )}} \delta (x- \sqrt{\pi (n+\frac 1 2)}) \frac{1}{x^2} =\\= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^\infty dx\, \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi (n+\frac 1 2 )}} \delta (x- \sqrt{\pi (n+\frac 1 2)})\frac{1}{x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2 (\pi (n+\frac 1 2 ))^{3/2}}$$

This converges absolutely, as can be seen by evaluating the integral and exploiting monotonicity.

Another way to get the result is by direct substitution: $d(x^2) = 2 x\,dx, \frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{2 x dx}{2 (x^2)^{3/2}}$

$$\int_0^\infty dx\,\frac{\delta (\cos x^2 )}{x^2} = \int_0^\infty d\xi\,\frac{\delta (\cos \xi )}{2 \xi^{3/2}} $$
Here, one has to account for the zeros
$$\xi  = \pi (n + \frac 1 2)$$
and thus
$$\dots = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(\pi (n+\frac 1 2))^{3/2}}$$